# Flutter(Dart) cannot remove from unmodifiable list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, crud

I am using tinder swipe cards. It has the following property:

```
          swipeCompleteCallback:
               (CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index) {
                    
                    updateStack(index);

               },
            ),
```

updateStack function:

```
    class _TinderCardsState extends State<TinderCards>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      List lstUsers = [];
      int lstUsersLength = 0;
     
     @override
     void initState() {
          super.initState();
          setState(() {
            lstUsers = users;
            lstUsersLength = users.length;
          });
      }

      void updateStack(int index) {
          setState(() {
           
              lstUsersLength = lstUsersLength - 1;
              lstUsers.removeAt(index);
          });
     }
```

So basically just trying to remove the top card from the stack. I am getting the above error even when it is a stateful widget.
Why am I getting this error?

The data (just a dart file with a list, no class or anything):

```
      const List users = [
{
 "id": "p1",
 "name": "John Doe",
 "age": "44",
 "imageUrl":
    "assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
"profession": "Financial Consultant"
 },
  ....
]
```

Comment: can you show us what error you are exactly getting?

Comment: Maybe not related to problem but : `lstUsers.remove(index)' will try to remove the item ìndex`from the list. 

You should use `lstUsers.removeAt(index)`.

Also `lstUsers.removeWhere((item) => index == index);`will delete all items of your list because `(index == index)` will always be true. Maybe you got the error  with this part uncommented?

Comment: What's the definition of users list? You're assigning lstUsers to users lstUsers = users; Is users a modifiable list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove const before `List users = [...]`.

You're declaring users as a compile-time constant. That's what makes it unmodifiable.

In dart, objects are passed by reference. When you write `lstUsers = users;` lstUsers becomes a 'view' of users and then becomes unmodifiable as well.

Another way to avoid that is :
`lstUsers = users.toList()`. It then gives lstUsers the value of a new list created from users.

Comment: Can't believe I couldn't see that.

Comment: I edited to include another way that allows for users to stay a constant.

Answer (score 4):

**Heres a simple solution**

Since your list is immutable you must create a new list but don't make it an instance if the original just make a copy.

```html
List<OnlineChannelUser> userList = List.from(response.data); 
userList.removeWhere((item) => item.uid == currentUid);
print(userList);  //new modified list
```